# Something is adding dirty code to my http post angular/ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an API REST with symfony 4 and an app with Ionic.

I'm just testing some methods from my API through my Ionic App,I can see something added to my URL

The error that i retrieve is the following:

```
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
clock-service.service.ts:23:8
```

As you can see the url that i pass is http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in but the response that i receive is Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in:, obviously the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in: returns a 404 error.

Something wrong in my code ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClockService {

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }



setClock() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Bearer', 'the_bearer_here' );
    const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.httpClient.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in', requestOptions)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['body']);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't look like the URl is getting changed, its the errror returned by the API for the invoked endpoint, `:`(colon) may be for the error message. Are you able to do the same request through Postman?

Comment: I believe if you are just referring to the : (colon) at the end it's just  formatting placed in the error message. It is not changing the url in any way!

Comment: I refer to colon, Yes. Through postman works without any problem. I keep investigating my service in angular,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related with CORS in my API, it was my mistake.

Thanks for your time.

The final angular code:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClockService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  setClock() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer the_bearer_code'
      })
    };
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/clock/in', httpOptions)
    .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data['body']);
});
  }
}
```